# SQL Lab Exercise

Tags: sql, command-line

I'm supposed to create a query that displays the the job_id, no of job_id, sum(salary) and ave(salary)

Possible outcome:

```
JOB_ID    NO. OF JOB_ID    SUM(SALARY)    AVE(SALARY)
-------------------------------------------------------
IT_PROG         3             10200          5100
AC_MGR          1             12000          12000
. 
.
. 
12 rows selected.
```

MY INPUT IS BELOW but I cannot get the output that was said above.
I need to group their salaries according to their job id but I cant input the job_id as it is not a group by function

```
 SQL > SELECT JOB_ID, COUNT(MAX(JOB_ID)) AS "NO. OF JOB_ID", SUM(SALARY), AVG(SALARY)
 2  FROM EMPLOYEES
 3  GROUP BY JOB_ID, SALARY;
```

What am I doing wrong? Thank you

Comment: Remove `SALARY` from the `GROUP BY`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is the code that you need for your output:

```
SELECT job_id, COUNT(job_id) AS "NO. OF JOB_ID", SUM(salary), AVG(salary)
FROM employees
GROUP BY job_id;
```

The problem was that you weren't only grouping by job_id, but also by salary, which prevented you for getting sum and averge of salaries for that job_id (It didn't get the average for that job_id but for that job_id AND that salary aka it was getting the very same salary).

Besides that, MAX is not needed for counting the number of occurrences of that job_id.

I hope I helped :)

Comment: Thank you so much! and for explaining it, I didnt see that problem. THANK YOU

Comment: No problem, glad to help :)

Comment: @Pengu Unfortunately it is not possible to assign more than one answer as a correct one. If you could return to assigning my answer as a correct one, I would appreciate it, as it's correct and the first one posted (you can see the older answer by sorting on the 'answer section' header. Tnx :)

Comment: sure I'm sorry I was not sure how this works, but I assigned yours as the correct one :) Thank youu so much

Answer (score 1):

You have more than one error.  Almost no database supports nested aggregation functions.  Second, you have `SALARY` in the `GROUP BY`.  That doesn't make sense, because you want calculations on `SALARY`.

So, the query is presumably more like:

```
SELECT JOB_ID, COUNT(*) AS "NO. OF JOB_ID", SUM(SALARY), AVG(SALARY)
FROM EMPLOYEES e
GROUP BY JOB_ID;
```

If you want the results in a particular order (such as by `COUNT(*)`, then you should include an explicit `ORDER BY`.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just got confused because it always show an error whenever I'm using the GROUP BY function and I dont include it in the GROUP BY. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You were grouping the result with the salary field too which is also being used in the calculation. You just have to remove the field from the gorup by and it will work like a charm.

> SELECT JOB_ID, COUNT(*) AS "NO. OF JOB_ID", SUM(SALARY) as
>   "SUM(SALARY)", AVG(SALARY) as "AVG(SALARY)" FROM EMPLOYEES GROUP BY
>   JOB_ID

Comment: thank you so much for taking time to reply and helping me

Comment: yes i upvoted you! but i only have less than 15 reputation and it doesnt allow me to let it stay up.

Comment: oh no worries :)